# How to create a new DB or connect to existing one

Tags: python-3.x, neo4j, neo4j-driver

I pulled and run neo4j docker:

```
sudo docker run -p7474:7474 -p7687:7687 -e NEO4J_AUTH=neo4j/s3cr3t neo4j
```

From python I can connect to it with:

```
scheme = "neo4j"
host_name = "localhost"
port = 7687
url = "{scheme}://{host_name}:{port}".format(scheme=scheme, host_name=host_name, port=port)
user = "neo4j"
password = "s3cr3t"
driver = GraphDatabase.driver(url, auth=(user, password))
```

But it seems that there is no API to choose the `DB name` I want to work with ?

- Is it possible to create multiple databases (like `postgres` `psycopg2` `connect` function with `dbname` ?)
- I want to be able to create 2 different DBs (graphs) and to choose the DB (graph) to work with through python
- How can I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To connect to a specific database, you can pass the database's name as the value of the [`database` keyword argument](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-python-driver/blob/8f708fe9374f7e6bdfdf84ff611f266a8a5e9344/docs/source/api.rst#database) when you create the [Session](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-python-driver/blob/8f708fe9374f7e6bdfdf84ff611f266a8a5e9344/docs/source/api.rst#session) used for your transactions.

For example, to create a Session for the database named "foo":

```
...
driver = GraphDatabase.driver(uri, auth=(user, password))
session = driver.session(database="foo")
...
```